# My program reads on of my properties as undefined

Tags: javascript, ejs

So I am trying to fix my starting page on my website but it just printing out my error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username') this is my error

I tried to fix my error by deleting it but it keept on printing out the error but with a different property so I think the problem is not that property but singleHighscore

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const db = require("../queries");

/* GET home page. */
router.get("/", async function (req, res, next) {
  const highscore = await db.getHighscore(1);
  const game = await db.getGame(1);
  const games = await db.getGames(10);
  const highscores = await db.getHighscores(10);
  const searchGames = await db.getSearch("C");
  res.render("index", {
    title: "Express",
    games: games,
    highscores: highscores,
    singleHighscore: highscore,
    singleGame: game,
    searchGames: searchGames,
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

This top code is the one that affect the bottom code

```
<div>
  <p><%=singleHighscore.username%></p>
  <p><%=singleHighscore.game.name%></p>
  <p><%=singleHighscore.score%></p>
  <p><%=singleHighscore.active%></p>
</div>
```

This is bottom code affect the get getHighscores

```
const getHighscore = async (id) => {
  let highscore;
  const pool = new Pool(credentials);

  await pool
    .query(`SELECT * FROM public.highscores WHERE id= ${id}`)
    .then((res) => {
      highscore = res.rows[0];
    });
  if (highscore && highscore.hasOwnProperty("gameid"))
    await pool
      .query(`SELECT * FROM public.games WHERE id= ${highscore.gameid}`)
      .then((res) => (highscore.game = res.rows[0]));

  return highscore;
};
```

Comment: You are right, `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'username')` means that whatever you are trying to read `username` from is undefined, not the `username` itself. So in this case it is the `singleHighscore`.

Comment: anyway I could fix that?

Comment: nothing sticks out to me in this code. You could wrap your queries in a `try...catch` block to handle errors but why your queries return undefined needs debugging. There are not enough details shared by you to debug this error.

Comment: I added one more code snippet that might help. I don't know what is wrong with my code

Comment: I also added console.log(highscore) over res.render("index",{: But i didn't get any output

Comment: I really don't know anything about databases but to me it's weird that you use await and then in the same context, you could check there if it causes any problems
For instance instead:
await pool
    .query(\`SELECT * FROM public.highscores WHERE id= ${id}\`)
    .then((res) => {
      highscore = res.rows[0];
    });
Try: 
highscore = await pool
     .query(`SELECT * FROM public.highscores WHERE id= ${id}\`)
     .rows[0];

Comment: I tried that but nothing seemed to change